# Segmentation fault while casting and dereferencing a void*

Tags: c, multithreading, casting

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <pthread.h>

    #define EXIT_ON_NOT_ZERO(assignment, msg) if((assignment)!=0) { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    void* produce(void* args) {
      return (void*) 1;
    }

    void* consume(void* args) {
      return (void*) 1;
    }

    int main() {
      pthread_t producer;
      pthread_t consumer;
      void* producerStatus;
      void* consumerStatus;
      EXIT_ON_NOT_ZERO(pthread_create(&producer, NULL, &produce, NULL), "Creating producer thread");
      EXIT_ON_NOT_ZERO(pthread_create(&consumer, NULL, &consume, NULL), "Creating consumer thread");
      EXIT_ON_NOT_ZERO(pthread_join(producer, &producerStatus), "Joining producer thread");
      EXIT_ON_NOT_ZERO(pthread_join(consumer, &consumerStatus), "Joining consumer thread");
      printf("Producer exited with status: %d\n", *(int*)producerStatus);
      printf("Consumer exited with status: %d\n", *(int*)consumerStatus);
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

I don't understand why I cannot cast and dereference at the same time.

Code is causing a `SEGFAULT` when it reaches the first `printf`.

Comment: What do you expect `printf` will display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that because `(void *) 1` returns the address `0x01` and dereferencing it is most likely undefined behavior.

Maybe, you want to cast "*the address*" to `intptr_t` which is perfectly valid as per the standard.

Comment: `(void *) 1` is not safely derived pointer, and is implementation defined at best.

Comment: @SergeyA Still you can use it safely if you don't dereference it AFAIK. Otherwise please give a link to the appropriate section of the standard when you have time.

Comment: @inarob, this is one of the darkest corners of Standard. pointers which are not safely derived are invalid pointer values. And standard has wording which allows one to assume that even having invalid pointer value in your program (without dereferencing it!) leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @iharob: Thanks man, so how can i return an integer value safely?

Comment: @iharob: Oh wait, I see. I was meant to return the value 1, not the address 0x01. Thanks again.

Comment: @berna995 You can't, you need to use pointers for that. Read about storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

I write this type of code in the following way (declare, allocate, assign and cast void* the return result), instead of using `return (void*)1`. In your example it would look somewhat like this:

```
void* produce(void* args) {
 int *pret = calloc(1,sizeof(int)); 
 *pret = 1;
 return (void*) pret;
}

void* consume(void* args) {
 int *cret = calloc(1,sizeof(int));
 *cret = 1;
 return (void*) cret;    
}
```

Terminal output:

```
Producer exited with status: 1
Consumer exited with status: 1
```

Hope this helps. Else you run into *segfault* problems caused by storage duration - as briefly mentioned in one of the previous comments. Please make sure to thoroughly read relevant material on POSIX thread programming...